# Laravel-Twilio Video Chat 'getUserMedia' error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, twilio

I am trying to implement the Twilio programmable video chat with Laravel and Javascript. But it shows the following error:

> WARN in [createLocalTracks #1]: Call to getUserMedia failed: Error:
> "getUserMedia is not supported"

I am currently working on localhost and don't configure it out. Is this any issue of ssl or localhost ? How can I solve that ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: which Browser are you using ? getUserMedia is supported by limited Browsers (and their versions) , check on Twilio Video documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are numbers of issues with getUserMedia:

1. Browser: You need to check if the browser you are using supports the `navigator.mediaDevices`.
2. SSL: As you are running it locally, you need to make sure it is loaded securely on `https`. If you have a problem to setup SSL on your local machine, deploy it on Heroku or something similar.

Read more on getUserMedia: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Security